# SDL_PollEvent not picking up all events

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm currently playing around with SDL to make a game and I've run into a problem where SDL is not picking up some events. For exampling, I would be pressing 'w' to move forward and at the same time, I'm moving my mouse to look around. But let's say I then press 'a' or 'd', SDL will not pick these events or even when I release 'w', SDL will not pickup the KEYUP event. I first wrote this code in windows and it all worked fine, but after switching to ubuntu, it doesn't work as expected anymore. Here is my main loop where I poll for events:

```
while(Running)
{
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        Events(&event);
    if( active ){
        Loop();
        Render();
    }
}
```

This is the code within Events():

```
switch(Event->type)
    {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            Running = false;
            break;
        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
            switch(Event->key.keysym.sym)
            {
                case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                    Running = false;
                    break;
                case SDLK_a:
                    keyStates['a'] = true;
                    break;
                case SDLK_s:
                    keyStates['s'] = true;
                    break;
                case SDLK_d:
                    keyStates['d'] = true;
                    break;
                case SDLK_w:
                    keyStates['w'] = true;
                    break;
                case SDLK_LSHIFT:
                    camera.setSpeed(2.0f);
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case SDL_KEYUP:
            switch(Event->key.keysym.sym)
            {
                case SDLK_a:
                    keyStates['a'] = false;
                    break;
                case SDLK_s:
                    keyStates['s'] = false;
                    break;
                case SDLK_d:
                    keyStates['d'] = false;
                    break;
                case SDLK_w:
                    keyStates['w'] = false;
                    break;
                case SDLK_LSHIFT:
                    camera.setSpeed(1.0f);
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            switch(Event->button.button)
            {
                case SDL_BUTTON_MIDDLE:
                    mouse.middle = true;
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            switch(Event->button.button)
            {
                case SDL_BUTTON_MIDDLE:
                    mouse.middle = false;
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
            if( moving ){
                camera.lookat(float(Event->motion.x - winWidth/2),float(Event->motion.y - winHeight/2), MOUSE_SENSITIVITY, dt);
                SDL_EventState(SDL_MOUSEMOTION, SDL_IGNORE);
                SDL_WarpMouse(winWidth/2, winHeight/2);
                SDL_EventState(SDL_MOUSEMOTION, SDL_ENABLE);
            }
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> keyStates['a'] = true;

There's `SDL_GetKeyState` for this. Use it instead of manually maintaining array.

```
Uint8 keys[SDLK_LAST];
Uint8* sdlKeys = SDL_GetKeyState(0);
memcpy(keys, sdlKeys, sizeof(keys));
```

.

```
bool keyPressed(SDLKey key){
    return keys[key] == SDL_PRESSED;
}
```

Also check [documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/FrontPage).

Comment: -1: link to the front page isn't really going to guide the OP to an answer to the problem without unnecessary info.  Sure it makes them read and eventually come to the answer, but there's a whole bunch of extras that doesn't help solve the problem.

Comment: @user2738698: Dude. Check the DATE of the question and the answer.

Comment: So?  It won't help future people either.  Most of the answer is fine, the link to the front page won't help anyone looking to get the problem solved.

Comment: Well, suit yourself. You might as well go ahead and write your own answer, though.